# This SQL request call all time and overload my server : SELECT meta_value FROM wp_sitemeta WHERE meta_key = 'wp_installer_network' AND site_id = 1

Tags: sql, performance

I have this SQL request who is call every time on my website and take between 1 and 2 secondes to execute so my serveur break down.
What is it and how delete it ?

```
SELECT meta_value FROM wp_sitemeta WHERE meta_key = 'wp_installer_network' AND site_id = 1
```

My site is a multisite multilanguale.
Thank you

Comment: it's not a part of WordPress itself, most likely your multilingual plugin, you should contact their support or ask other users ( a quick copy paste search on github suggests WPML ). As for how to remove it, you can deactivate the plugin, but for help with WPML you have to ask WPML support or ask in a WPML community. _You can't ask for help with 3rd party plugins/products/services here as that's offtopic and not in this stacks scope_

Answer (score 0):

> What is it

It's most likely a part of the WPML. This is based on a quick copy paste of `wp_installer_network` into the github search box.

There's also a small chance this is the Types plugin, but you mentioned you had a multilingual plugin installed.

No references to `wp_installer_network` are found in WordPress itself.

> and how delete it ?

You would need to ask this in a WPML community but the easiest way is to deactivate WPML. If you want to keep WPML but still resolve the problem you will need to ask this in a WPML community as 3rd party plugin questions are offtopic here